# Proving $ab>0$ when $a,b>0$ or $a,b<0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $\forall a, b ∈\mathbb Z$, we say that $a > b$ if $a−b := a+ (−b) ∈Z^+$. 
>   Show that, $\forall a,b∈ \mathbb Z$, we have $a·b >0$ if $a, b >0$ or $a, b <0$.

My attempt:

First I show that case where $a,b>0$.

Let $a=[(j,1)]$ such that $j\ge2$ and $b=[(k,1)]$ such that $k\ge2$

So,$ab=[(jk+1,j+k)]$ where $j,k\geq2$

Now, $ab$ is positive if we can show there exists $x\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ such that $j+k+x=jk+1$ .

I am stuck here. No idea how to prove such an $x$ exits.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot that $a>b$, which means that $j>k$. So, since $k\geqslant2$, you have $j\geqslant3$. And then\begin{align}jk+1-(j+k)&=jk+1-j-k\\&=(j-1)k+1-k\\&\geqslant2(k-1)-k+1\\&=k-1\\&\geqslant1.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Proceed by induction on $b$, supposing that $a>0$.

$a.1=a>0$ and if by hypothesis $a.b>0$, $a.(b+1)=a.b+a>0$ as the some of two positive integers is positive.

You can deal with $a,b<0$ in a similar way.

Comment: Would the downvoter be so kind to explain?